# Why my Mocha tests (Async/Await) passes but throw an error at the same time?

Tags: node.js, async-await, mocha.js

I am new to Mocha and I have been struggling trying to test a function that uses a token generated by a web service. The test passes but an error is thrown in the end. The problem seems to be related to the Async/Await functions.

If I comment out the .end function, the test passes.
Debugging I can see the res.status is 500, that means the await is not working...

My test file code is as below:

```
var supertest = require("supertest");
var should = require("should");
const getToken = require("./getToken");

var server = supertest.agent("http://localhost:3000");

// Testing alarmStatusController
//  

describe("Get Alarm Status", () => {

    it("should return a json file and 200 if token valid", async () => {
        let token = await getToken.getValidToken();
        server
            .get("/api/node/path")
            .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token)
            .expect("Content-type", /json/)
            .expect(200)
            .end(function (err, res) {

                res.status.should.equal(200);
                res.body.message.should.equal('Alarms fetched successfully');

            });
    });

});
```

The result of the test is:

```
Get Alarm Status
     √ should return a json file and 200 if token valid (38ms)

    1 passing (38ms)


C:\Dev\Globalwatch3\WebServices\GlobalwatchApi\node_modules\should\cjs\should.js:254
  throw new AssertionError(params);
  ^
AssertionError: expected 500 to be 200
at Assertion.fail (C:\Dev\Globalwatch3\WebServices\GlobalwatchApi\node_modules\should\cjs\should.js:275:17)
at Assertion.value (C:\Dev\Globalwatch3\WebServices\GlobalwatchApi\node_modules\should\cjs\should.js:356:19)
at Test.<anonymous> (C:\Dev\Globalwatch3\WebServices\GlobalwatchApi\test\alarmStatus_test.js:29:39)
at Test.assert (C:\Dev\Globalwatch3\WebServices\GlobalwatchApi\node_modules\supertest\lib\test.js:181:6)
at localAssert (C:\Dev\Globalwatch3\WebServices\GlobalwatchApi\node_modules\supertest\lib\test.js:131:12)
at C:\Dev\Globalwatch3\WebServices\GlobalwatchApi\node_modules\supertest\lib\test.js:128:5
at Test.Request.callback (C:\Dev\Globalwatch3\WebServices\GlobalwatchApi\node_modules\superagent\lib\node\index.js:728:3)
at parser (C:\Dev\Globalwatch3\WebServices\GlobalwatchApi\node_modules\superagent\lib\node\index.js:916:18)
at IncomingMessage.res.on (C:\Dev\Globalwatch3\WebServices\GlobalwatchApi\node_modules\superagent\lib\node\parsers\json.js:19:7)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:203:15)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1129:12)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

Hope somebody can help...
Thanks

Comment: `server.end` is asynchronous function with `callback`. So your test case ends after you call `server.end` instead of waiting for it to be done. You need to use `done` in your test.

Answer (score 1):

You could use promise instead of `end` callback:

```
const supertest = require("supertest");
const should = require("should");
const getToken = require("./getToken");
const server = supertest.agent("http://localhost:3000");

describe("Get Alarm Status", () => {

    it("should return a json file and 200 if token valid", async () => {
        let token = await getToken.getValidToken();

        const res = await server
            .get("/api/node/path")
            .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token)
            .expect("Content-type", /json/)
            .expect(200);

        res.status.should.equal(200);
        res.body.message.should.equal('Alarms fetched successfully');
    });

});
```